Different Starting Indices for Iterating over Large Files
I want to begin by saying I have NOT programmed in many, many years, so sorry if this is a somewhat trivial question. My interest has been mathematics for the last couple of years
Here's my code:
lastStop = False

with open('K3.txt','r') as K3:
    with open('K4.txt','a') as K4:
        for tri0 in K3:
            tri = tri0.split(',')
            c=tri[2][:-1]
            c=int(c)
            a=tri[0]
            b=tri[1]
            a=int(a)
            b=int(b)
            for d in range(c+1,6821):
                if lastStop:
                    if [adjMat[a][d],adjMat[b][d],adjMat[c][d]]==['1','1','1']:
                        K4.write(str(a)+','+str(b)+','+str(c)+','+str(d)+'\n')
                elif str(a)+','+str(b)+','+str(c)+','+str(d)+'\n'=='670,3016,3426,5603\n':
                    lastStop=True

In this, I'm iterating over the lines of a very large file (K3.txt), doing some processing, and then writing to K4.txt. But, because it takes so long, I ran it over night last night. Because of that, I didn't get all the way through it, and the last line that I wrote to K4 was '670,3016,3426,5603\n'
I'm planning on running this again tonight, wanting to start right after I get to the (a,b,c,d)=670,3016,3426,5603 point in the for loops, and my solution here doesn't feel elegant. I set a boolean "lastStop" to False, and then, once I get to that (a,b,c,d) value, I turn it to true so it starts running that first part of the if/elif statement
I'm sure I'm losing a lot of time by having to go through all values up until that point
I'm thinking there surely must be a way to start the "for tri0 in K3:" for loop at (a,b,c)=(670,3016,3426) point, but I'm not sure how to do that without looping over the row numbers, and Pythonista for some reason interprets K3 as a list sometimes and not a list other times
For example, the a=tri[0] followed immediately by a=int(a) is because, for some reason, when I write "a=int(tri[0])", Pythonista throws me an error along the lines of "Object 'type' cannot be subindexed" (if you want the exact error, I can find out)
I hope this made sense; thank you

How big is the K3 file?

@vassiliev It's about 2 gb. I don't know how large that is relative to other people's work, but I'm running this on a very old iPhone; I don't own a computer.

It seems that you write a line out for every line you read in.
Thus you can start by checking the number of lines in the output file, and then skip that number of lines before resuming the processing.
This should let start your script repeatedly in case it still does not finish in time.

First of all, I don't have a Pythonista environment so I can not test the code similarly. Sorry for that.
I just provide some idea for you to solve this problem.
The last line of K4 is '670,3016,3426,5603\n', which means:

the last line of K3 you have read starts with '670,3016,3426'.
the last d is 5603.

I think you can try searching '\n670,3016,3426' and start a new loop from the next '\n' from that position. Like:
with open('K3.txt','r') as K3:
    content = K3.read()
    sub_string = '\n670,3016,3426'
    pos_linesep = 0
    while 1:
        pos_new = content.find(sub_string, pos_linesep)
        if pos_new > 0:
            pos_linesep = content.find('\n', pos_new + 1)
            if pos_linesep <= pos_new:
                raise Exception  # can't find the position of last stop
            line = content[pos_new: pos_linesep]
            a, b, c = line.split(',')
            if adjMat[int(a)][5603] == adjMat[int(b)][5603] == adjMat[int(c)][5603] == '1':
                break
        else:
            # can't find the position of last stop
            raise Exception

    K3.seek(pos_linesep + 1)  # start from the position of last stop
    with open('K4.txt','a') as K4:  # codes below is basiclly your origin
        for tri0 in K3:
            tri = tri0.split(',')
            c=tri[2][:-1]
            c=int(c)
            a=tri[0]
            b=tri[1]
            a=int(a)
            b=int(b)
            for d in range(c+1,6821):
                if [adjMat[a][d],adjMat[b][d],adjMat[c][d]]==['1','1','1']:
                    K4.write(str(a)+','+str(b)+','+str(c)+','+str(d)+'\n')

